# Hide Excel Columns Based on User Selections

Tags: vba, excel-2010

I have a Validation List in cell B2 that obtains a list from ROW 5 (G5:BF5).

I want the user to be able to select a value from the Validation List which results in all columns from G to BF being hidden EXCEPT for the column header that matches the value in cell B2.

I have used the below code, but keep getting an Application-Defined or Object-Defined error.

I'm using the below VBA:

Worksheet >> Change

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    If Target.Address = "$B$2" Then
    Dim the_selection As String
    Dim week_in_review As String
    the_selection = Worksheets("SortHeatMap").Range("B2")
    Dim rep As Integer
    For rep = 8 To 25
    the_column = GetColumnLetter_ByInteger(rep)
    week_in_review = Worksheets("SortHeatMap").Range(column_letter & "5")
    If the_selection = week_in_review Then
    Worksheets("SortHeatMap").Range(the_column & ":" & the_column).EntireColumn.Hidden = False
    Else
    Worksheets("SortHeatMap").Range(the_column & ":" & the_column).EntireColumn.Hidden = True
    End If
    Next rep
    End If

End Sub
```

And this in the (General) >> GetColumnLetter_ByInteger in Module 1.

```
Public Function GetColumnLetter_ByInteger(what_number As Integer) As String

    'This section obtains Column letter of selected week.

    GetColumnLetter_ByInteger = ""

    If MyColumn_integer <= 26 Then
    column_letter = Chr(64 + MyColumn_integer)
    End If

    If MyColumn_integer > 26 Then
    column_letter = Chr(Int((MyColumn_integer - 1) / 26) + 64) & Chr(((MyColumn_integer - 1) Mod 26) + 65)
    End If

    GetColumnLetter_ByInteger = column_letter

End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should do it:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim rep As Long, v
    If Target.Address = Me.Range("B2").Address Then
        v = Target.Value
        For rep = 8 To 25
            Me.Columns(rep).Hidden = (Me.Cells(5, rep).Value <> v)
        Next rep
    End If
End Sub
```

When you're in the worksheet code module you can use `Me` to refer to the worksheet.

Converting column numbers to letters is a pain and you never really need to do it.

Comment: Thanks!  I'll let you know how it turns out.

Comment: @Tim Williams There should be no need to use the `Me` identifier because if no worksheet is specified the active one will be used, and the active one can't be any other than the one that triggered the change event. Given your huge experience, I wonder if you have come across situations where not specifying the tab in worksheet event procedures - whether using `Me` or otherwise - had a detrimental effect.

Comment: @Variatus -  I typically use `Me` because it's more explicit, not because it's required.  Similarly I typically add `Value` instead or relying on the default property of `Range`.    However - "the active one can't be any other than the one that triggered the change event" is not always true: the change could be the result of a macro and doesn't need the sheet to be active.  Luckily though the sheet module always defaults to itself and not ActiveSheet

Comment: @Tim Williams Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This code will first hide all the columns in the specified range and then show the one you specified in B2. The advantage of this system is that the previously shown column will be among the hidden.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    Const TriggerCell As String = "B2"
    Const FirstColumnToHide As String = "G"
    Const LastColumnToHide = "BF"

    Dim Rng As Range
    Dim ClmToShow As Variant

    With Target
        If .Address = Range(TriggerCell).Address Then
            Application.ScreenUpdating = False
            ClmToShow = .Value
            On Error Resume Next
            ClmToShow = Columns(ClmToShow).Column
            If ClmToShow < Columns(FirstColumnToHide).Column Or _
               ClmToShow > Columns(LastColumnToHide).Column Then Exit Sub
            ' if TriggerCell doesn't contain a qualified column reference
            ' this would also be the case if an error occurred at this point

            On Error GoTo 0
            Set Rng = Range(Columns(FirstColumnToHide), Columns(LastColumnToHide))
            Rng.Columns.Hidden = True
            Columns(ClmToShow).Hidden = False
            Application.ScreenUpdating = True
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

Whenever practical to  implement, avoid having constants interspersed into the code. Here it is easy to do. All constants are declared at the top of the code. If there are changes in the future they can be done there, without touching the code itself.

Comment: Thanks!  I'll let you know how it turns out.